# Mongo DB projection issue

Tags: mongodb, projection

I have a data model as

```
 {
        "_id" : "corks",
        "Zm9vYmFyYmF6" : {
            "metadata" : {
                "type" : "fooType",
                "version" : 1,
                "format" : "binary"
            },
            "value" : "some value"
        },
        "Zm9vYmFyYmF6enJheg==" : {
            "metadata" : {
                "type" : "barType",
                "version" : 1,
                "format" : "binary"
            },
            "value" : "other value"
        },
       ...
    }
```

The identifiers Zm9vYmFyYmF6, ... - lets name them KEYS -  are something which i can not easily determine , can have arbitrary value.

This model fits well to most of use cases but is poor when i want to project document only to certain KEYS matching metadata.type == fooBar

On the other hand i wanted to avoid the array in the model it self to simplify other operations (which i will skip for brevity)

How can i project the content of the document to the array of elements
so that later on i can match on.

```
[
    {
            "metadata" : {
                "type" : "fooType",
                "version" : 1,
                "format" : "binary"
            },
            "value" : "some value"
        },
        {
            "metadata" : {
                "type" : "barType",
                "version" : 1,
                "format" : "binary"
            },
            "value" : "other value"
        },
       ...
]
```

Is there a way to dynamically bypass top level attribute ?

Comment: it would be better to restructure how the data is stored if you can tbh

Comment: I had idea of different model 


      `{ "_id" : "corks", 
   [     "metadata" : {         "type" : "fooType",  "version" : 1,      "format" : "binary"   "value" : {  "key1" : "value1",  "key2"  : ....    } },  }, ]   }`


But this hugely complicates all logic to operate on array  .....